# How to update Firestore document when data changes when collected from 3rd Party API instead of creating new document

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

The code below is set up to collect data from a 3rd party API for NBA games. At the moment it all works and the data is stored in GCP Firestore but the issue is that it creates a new document for each game every time you make an API call. So say it's called 3 times a day there will be 3 different documents for the same game.

What I would like to happen is that each time the API is called and the game's data has changed it updates the original document instead of creating a new one.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import requests
import json
from firebase_admin import firestore

db = firestore.Client(project='xxxx')


def bluebet_nba_odds():
    # MAKE VARIABLES GLOBAL
    global away_team_win_odds, away_team, home_team_win_odds, home_team, start_time, event_title, event_id, competition

    # API CALL

    link = 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.com.au/json/reply/MasterCategoryRequest?EventTypeID=107&WithLevelledMarkets' \
           '=true&WithLevelledMarkets=true '
    # Request data from link as 'str'
    nbadata = requests.get(link).text
    # convert 'str' to Json
    nbadata = json.loads(nbadata)

    # JSON PARSE

    for nba_odds in nbadata['MasterCategories'][2]['Categories'][0]['MasterEvents']:
        competition = nba_odds['CategoryName']
        event_id = nba_odds['MasterEventId']
        event_title = nba_odds['MasterEventName']
        start_time = nba_odds['MaxAdvertisedStartTime']
        home_team = nba_odds['Markets'][0]['OutcomeName']
        home_team_win_odds = nba_odds['Markets'][0]['Price']
        away_team = nba_odds['Markets'][1]['OutcomeName']
        away_team_win_odds = nba_odds['Markets'][1]['Price']

# WRITE TO FIRESTORE

        data = {
            'competition': competition,
            'event_id': event_id,
            'event_title': event_title,
            'start_time': start_time,
            'home_team': home_team,
            'home_team_win_odds': home_team_win_odds,
            'away_team': away_team,
            'away_team_win_odds': away_team_win_odds,
            'timestamp': firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP,
            }

        db.collection('bluebet_nba_season_odds').document().set(data), print('Game Data Written to Firestore')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bluebet_nba_odds()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document()` with no arguments generats a random document ID every time it's called.  Don't do that.  Give the document a name instead.

```
db.collection('bluebet_nba_season_odds').document('you-choose-a-name-here')
```

You might be helped by reviewing the [API documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/index.html) to understand better how the API works, especially for the [document()](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/collection.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.base_collection.BaseCollectionReference.document) method that you're calling.

Comment: Can i auto generate the document name from event_title and perhaps the date? So "team_a_at_team_b_10_12_22" or something similar? This script will pull data for multiple games, so each day there will be between 2 and 11 games.

Comment: You can do whatever you want in your code.  Build the ID any way you like.  Just make sure it's the same every time you want to update the contents of that one document.  If you have a new problem with something specific to that task, please post a new question separately.